# I get an issue with borderRadius in flutter

Tags: flutter

Recently I update Flutter to the newest version, and I found an issue, when i try to add a borderRadius, the IDE indicates that i need to use borderRadiusGeometry, does somebody know how to fix it?

```
return Container(
            child: Card(
              child: Text('${myNumbers[index]}'),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadiusGeometry.lerp <<--- i need to replace this line
            ),
            height: 100,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
borderRadius: BorderRadiusGeometry.lerp
```

with

```
 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
```